# How can I be sure to catch all possible exceptions when uploading to Glacier with boto3 (AWS)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore

I am writing a small python application that uploads archives to AWS Glacier. During the upload process, I call the following methods:

- client.initiate_multipart_upload()
- client.upload_multipart_part()
- client.complete_multipart_upload()

All of these have the potential to raise many different exceptions if the connection is lost or the request takes too long.

I was using:

```
 except (botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError, client.exceptions.RequestTimeoutException):
```

to try and catch them, retry after a set period of time, and give up after a set number of attempts, but I still sometimes get other exceptions that go uncaught. Right now I have switched to using a blanket

```
except:
```

statement, which I am not very happy about. My application checks the AWS account credentials, vault name and connection to AWS at another stage, so these do not need to be considered. Is there a way I can catch all boto3 and botocore exceptions that might occur while carrying out these three methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`botocore.exceptions.BotoCoreError` is the base exception class for botocore exceptions.

`boto3.exceptions.Boto3Error` is the base exception class for all boto3 exceptions.

You should also watch out for `botocore.exceptions.ClientError` and `botocore.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError` which do not inherit `botocore.exceptions.BotoCoreError`.

Sources:

https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/exceptions.py
https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/exceptions.py

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I really appreciate the help